# display video in a frame in portrait mode using MPMediaPlayer

Tags: iphone, media-player

i have a requirement where i need to display a video at the center of the iPhone screen inside a frame.
Is there any way to do this using the basic MPMediaPlayer?
I have seen that using the MPMediaPlayer causes the video to play full screen in a landscape mode...
So, is there any way that this can be customized to suit my needs?
Thanks in advance!
^__^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out that it can be done in iOS4 atleast ... If you have the same requirements then check this link : http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-play-video-in-iphoneos4/